# Upgrade mysql version for MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, magento, server, mamp

I am trying to install the existing Magento project. I installed MAMP so that it included all the apache, PHP, MySQL, etc...

When I tried to import the database file, PHPMyAdmin returned an invalid formatting message. Then, I found that the database that I imported is using DB server version 8.0.X, and my DB server version is using 5.7.34. That's why I can't import the database file.

Is there any method so that I can upgrade the MAMP MySQL version to 8.0.28 or solve the importing problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Accordingly to the official documentation, Magento is not supported on Mac or Windows. See [system requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html) for more details.
[image]

Even if you manage to install it on your Mac using MAMP it will be **very slow** because of MacOs filesystem. I tried many different tools (mamp, valet, php -S, etc) and nothing make Magento works smoothly on a Mac, except Docker.

Besides that, the requirements for every magento version changes, making it very hard to update your environment if you plan to work with more than one version of Magento.

There are plenty of [Docker images out there](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=magento2&type=image), but for now, when you pick one of them, remember to not sync all of your files and folders with docker. I mean, if you want it to be 'usable', remember to only sync your `app/code` folder. See an example below:

```
services:
  app:
    volumes: &appvolumes
      ## Host mounts with performance penalty, only put what is necessary here
      - ./src/app/code:/var/www/html/app/code:cached
      - ./src/app/design:/var/www/html/app/design:cached
      - ./src/app/etc:/var/www/html/app/etc:cached
      - ./src/composer.json:/var/www/html/composer.json:cached
      - ./src/composer.lock:/var/www/html/composer.lock:cached
      - ./src/nginx.conf.sample:/var/www/html/nginx.conf:cached
      #- ./src/auth.json:/var/www/html/auth.json:cached
      #- ./src/m2-hotfixes:/var/www/html/m2-hotfixes:cached
      #- ./src/patches:/var/www/html/patches:cached
      - ./src/var/log:/var/www/html/var/log:cached
      #- ./src/var/report:/var/www/html/var/report:cached
      ## To sync your SSH to the container, uncomment the following line:
      #- ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      ## Linux only: remove the above lines (except nginx.conf line) and mount the entire src directory with:
      #- ./src:/var/www/html:cached
```